# How can i bind a table from oracle directly to pdf

Tags: asp.net, oracle

How can I bind data from oracle database to pdf in asp.net 4.0?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually i have used iText to bind data from table to pdf.first i have binded the data to grid view and then to pdf.It is working.But direct binding is complicated i know.But i have to do that.Please any one help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible directly. You might take a look at [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) for generating PDF files in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [PL/PDF](http://plpdf.com/) ?  Haven't used it personally, but its the only direct method of creating/populating PDFs out of Oracle that I know of (unless perhaps [Apex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html) has some plug-in)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you soo much for your responses. I got the answer. Below is the code for binding a database table from an Oracle database to PDF in ASP.net

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Data;

public partial class generate_pdf_from_dataset : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User id=book;Password=book;Data Source=test");
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from category" , con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 40, 25);
        System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, mStream);
        int cols = dt.Columns.Count;
        int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
        pdfDoc.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Table pdfTable = new iTextSharp.text.Table(cols, rows);
        pdfTable.BorderWidth = 1;
        pdfTable.Width = 100;
        pdfTable.Padding = 1;
        pdfTable.Spacing = 1;
        //creating table headers
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            Cell cellCols = new Cell();
            Font ColFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD);
            Chunk chunkCols = new Chunk(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, ColFont);
            cellCols.Add(chunkCols);
            pdfTable.AddCell(cellCols);
        }
        //creating table data (actual result)
        for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                Cell cellRows = new Cell();
                Font RowFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12);
                Chunk chunkRows = new Chunk(dt.Rows[k][j].ToString(), RowFont);
                cellRows.Add(chunkRows);
                pdfTable.AddCell(cellRows);
            }
        }
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```